# Is Robert Rutledge's calculation of the probability of similarities between Michelle Obama and Melania Trump's speeches reasonable?

Tags: probability, text-mining

Melania Trump has given a speech in support of her husband's campaign that many people believe has been plagiarised. An astrophysics professor, Robert Rutledge has calculated that there is a 1 in 87 billion chance that certain similarities in phrasing are coincidental. While not necessarily arguing the overall conclusion, given that word orders is restricted by grammar, and they were obviously talking about overlapping topics, this low probability seems too low. Are there methods to put a more realistic probability on coincidence that is conditional on these other features of the problem?

See related news article:

www.huffingtonpost.com.au/entry/math-melania-trump-plagiarism_us_578e66bbe4b04ca54ebef2b6

Comment: This question is loaded! There could be any which way you might want to compute a p-value. Odds are you will have to accept the alternate hypothesis, this is not a co-incidence :)

Comment: I guess I was reacting to how extreme the computed value was and suspecting that at least one simplifying assumption (that all combinations of words are valid) didn't make sense. I was far less interested in the overall conclusion than the method of getting there.

Comment: One in 87 billion (about $10^{-11}$) sounds conservatively high to me--it's easy to come up with plausible analyses that produce chances on the order of $10^{-100}$, $10^{-1000}$, and even smaller.  But to calculate any probability at all, one needs a probability model.  I wonder just what probability model would be a realistic description of *any* speech? What is blatantly missing from Rutledge's analysis is any recognition of its *post hoc* nature, or any adjustment for that.